# Google Ads: rx_lidar and abg_lite_fy2021 being called a dozen or so times

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads

On https://www.iq-mag.net/ I can see a dozen calls being made to:

- https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/rx_lidar.js?cache=r20110914
- https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20230213/r20110914/abg_lite_fy2021.js

My question is why are there a dozen calls being made? Could it just not be a single one?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected and normal. The page loads 13 ads. Each ad is rendered in an iframe and needs to load the files you mentioned. Files are cached so there is  no unnecessary network requests. But they still have to execute within each iframe independently, which is not ideal, but difficult to avoid.